# FormClosing event in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm doing a C# app with multiple Forms, like Help, Feedback, Register, Login, etc. I try to override the FormClosing, like when the user presses X in the upper right to close the form, to return to the previous form that was opened.

I tried something like this

```
private void QuestionForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
            this.Hide();
            HelpForm help = new HelpForm();
            help.FormClosed += (s, args) => this.Close();
            help.Show();
}
```

but when I press X, only the Question Form closes, and the Help Form that let's say was the previous one, shows up like 0.1s and the whole app closes.

Comment: Show us your event handler code.

Comment: Generally speaking, what you want to do is open your second form over the first form using ShowDialog.  ShowDialog is a blocking call, so when your user exits the second form, it will simply return to the line of code following the ShowDialog call.

Comment: A little more context of what you are trying.  Maybe calling the forms via ShowDialog() vs Show().  This will mean the DIALOG version must be completed and close before it returns back to the calling source. -- OR, do you WANT multiple different instances of these other forms to be loaded multiple times.  I would suspect not.

Comment: Okay, it seems I don't even need to override the FormClosing anymore if I'm using ShowDialog. After I close the Form it comes back to the caller. Thank you both Robert Harvey and DRapp for help and the ShowDialog suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acoording to the comments, We can find the solution to this problem is to use [ShowDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=windowsdesktop-6.0).

You can use this method to display a modal dialog box in your application.

When this method is called, the code following it is not executed until after the dialog box is closed.